# Fusionauth entering silent mode

Tags: mariadb, fusionauth

We are running fusionauth with mariadb in cluster with 3 nodes. Fusion auth is getting started in 2 of the nodes and entering in Silent mode in one of them. Is there a way to increase the number of attempts or is there a way to get this running on all three nodes without one entering the silent mode.

Answer (score 0):

FusionAuth will enter silent mode if the proper environment variables are defined, and if it needs to complete configuration.

If you are entering silent mode on only one of the 3 nodes perhaps that node does not have the correct JDBC connection or has a network issue of some type that would keep it from connecting to the search and database services on startup?

https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/installation-guide/docker